# I am trying to capture a screenshot for each failure but File.Utils or File.Handler are showing errors in code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public void getscreenshot() throws IOException{ 
    File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileHandler.copy(src,new File("*./Screenshots/facebook.png"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, make sure you have provided imports correctly
also new file path should start from ./ which means paste in current directory

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

public void getscreenshot() throws IOException{ 
    File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copy(src,new File("./Screenshots/facebook.png"));
}
```

Comment: thanks amit now i dont any see any error in code but while executing below code i have runtime error

Comment: public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) { 
      
      
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try {
    b.getscreenshot(result.getName());
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at resources.base.getscreenshot(base.java:62)
 at Academy.listeners.onTestFailure(listeners.java:35)
 at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:66)